# Android ViewPager/PagerAdapter with Data Binding and instantiateItem not executing active view

Tags: java, android

I am using Android data binding in a MVVM framework.  I have a ViewPager setup with a corresponding PagerAdapter.  Some of the pages may contain videos. The issue that I am having is that the instantiateItem method in the PagerAdapter always executes the next view in the PagerAdapter instead of the current view.  For example say page 1 has no video, but page 2 does. When the user views page 1, the video in page 2 starts playing. Here is the instantiateItem method:

```
     public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {     
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     

        ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.main_layout, null, false);     
        Post post = posts.get(position);
        myViewModel = new PostModel(post);     
        binding.setVariable(BR.model, myViewModel);   
        container.addView(binding.getRoot());     

        return binding.getRoot();     
    }
```

How can I make the instantiateItem execute the current view instead of the next view? Is the issue related to setOffscreenPageLimit?

Answer (score 2):

You can't because it's main idea of `ViewPager` - it preload next N pages in order to make swiping smooth. Also actually you can setup it in order to see part of next view.

I think you should use [OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html), and manager start/stop of playing of your video when it needed here.

Btw, some advices - you can use that [library](https://github.com/evant/binding-collection-adapter) in order to not write that boilerplate code at all. [Here my example of usage](https://github.com/kidinov/Retrofit_rx_binding_test/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/kidinov/retr_rx_test/viewModel/ActivityViewModel.java).

Comment: Have you used the binding-collection-adapter library? I'm looking into implementing. Related to the issue I'm having is the TextureView BindingAdapter I'm using to playback the video. From what I understand it plays when it senses the TextureView comes into the active view. However I need to have more control on when the TextureView gets triggered.  For example I may want to delay playback and also it's still triggering itself when a dialog view above is presented.